# Grouping modules in the Gradle generated ipr file

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I would like to group my modules within Intellij Idea. In the ipr file you can specify a group attribute on a module node within the ipr file. This is for a multi project build.

How can I specify the group attribute in the ipr module node? Ideally I would like to be able to specify the group in the subproject's build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use one of the provided hooks (namely `idea.project.ipr.withXml`) to post-process the `.ipr` file on the XML level. See [IdeaProject](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaProject.html) in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for details.

Comment: Not quite, it is the ipr that I need to adjust, not the module. But the module does not seem to have a group associated with it.

Comment: I just mixed up the words project and module. Fixed.